# wxwidgets aui manager problem

Tags: c++, user-interface, wxwidgets

i am using auimanager to show frame in a frame , however it keeps showing the second frame in a new window instead in the same window, or any other suggestions on how to do it ?

Comment: how about showing the code you have so that people can have an idea about what your problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "outer frame" should be a aui.AuiMDIParentFrame, whereas the "inner frame" should be aui.AuiMDIChildFrame.  In any case: post some code, then it is easier to advise.

Example code:

```
import wx
import aui

class MainFrame(aui.AuiMDIParentFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        aui.AuiMDIParentFrame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title="AuiMDIParentFrame",
                                       size=(640, 480), style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        child1 = InnerFrame(self, "child 1")
        child1.Show()
        child2 = InnerFrame(self, "child 2")
        child2.Show()


class InnerFrame(aui.AuiMDIChildFrame):
    def __init__(self, parent, label):
        aui.AuiMDIChildFrame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title=label)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = MainFrame(None)
    frame.CenterOnScreen()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: i already have a frame class which i can not modify , and now i just created a new frame and which i want to display the old frame in it and not as a new window , is that possible ?

Comment: Your new frame must be derived from AuiMDIChildFrame.  I'll edit my post to show an example.

Comment: please do, i've been trying to solve this for over 12 hours, thanks in advance